# Python sort dict of dicts by most values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to sort a dict of dicts by dict containg the most values.
 This is the original dict:

```
test = {u'Beta': {
        u'SW Engineering': {
                u'Resolved': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 9, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 12, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 11, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 9, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 12, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 11, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 9, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 10, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 11, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 9},
                u'In Testing': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 7, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 7, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 7, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 7, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 7, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 7, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 7, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 7, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 7},
                u'Reopened': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 1, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 1, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 1, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 1, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'Closed': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 17, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 18, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 18, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 17, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 18, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 18, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 17, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 18, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 18, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 17},
                u'Open': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 5, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 8, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 8, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 5, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 8, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 5, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 8, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 8, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 5}},
        u'DSP Engineering': {
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1}}}}
```

**And this is how I want it to look like:**

```
test = {u'Beta': {
        u'DSP Engineering': {
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1}},
        u'SW Engineering': {
                u'Resolved': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 9, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 12, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 11, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 9, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 12, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 11, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 9, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 10, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 11, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 9},
                u'In Testing': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 7, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 7, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 7, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 7, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 7, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 7, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 7, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 7, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 7},
                u'Reopened': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 1, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 1, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 1, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 1, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'Closed': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 17, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 18, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 18, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 17, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 18, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 18, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 17, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 18, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 18, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 17},
                u'Open': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 5, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 8, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 8, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 5, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 8, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 5, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 8, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 8, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 5}}}}
```

Comment: Python3.6? If not, you can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: Create an `OrderedDict` from a sorted list of pairs.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Probably not, with those u-strings.

Comment: @Ryan can you kindly provide an example?

Comment: Do you know how to sort a list?

Comment: Yes, by using sorted(test) or test.sort()

Comment: What is interesting in this case is what your intentions are. Did you create the data? In that case maybe rewrite the structure. Did you receive the data? In that case maybe make a conversion script to a format more of your liking.

Comment: I fetch the data once a day and save it in sqlite, which is then shown as plot in highcharts. Before plotting I basically build a dict and send it as output to Flask. So yes, I create the data. This is how the data is when it's not sorted: http://jsfiddle.net/02jbjxf4/ and this is how it's when it's sorted: http://jsfiddle.net/02jbjxf4/1/ and as you can see. Option is more elegant than the first one, since it doesn't ruin the plot

Answer (score 1):

An example how to do it with `OrderedDict`.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


test = {u'Beta': {
        u'SW Engineering': {
                u'Resolved': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 9, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 12, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 11, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 9, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 12, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 11, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 9, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 10, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 11, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 9},
                u'In Testing': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 7, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 7, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 7, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 7, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 7, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 7, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 7, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 7, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 7},
                u'Reopened': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 1, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 1, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 1, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 1, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'Closed': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 17, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 18, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 18, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 17, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 18, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 18, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 17, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 18, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 18, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 17},
                u'Open': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 5, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 8, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 8, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 5, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 8, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 5, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 8, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 8, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 5}},
        u'DSP Engineering': {
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1}}}}


engineers_tasks = []
for engineer, tasks in test['Beta'].items():
    tasks_sorted = sorted(tasks.items(), key=lambda k: len(k[1]), reverse=True)
    min_tasks = len(tasks_sorted[-1][1])
    engineers_tasks.append((engineer, OrderedDict(tasks_sorted), min_tasks))

engineers_tasks = sorted(engineers_tasks, key=lambda k: k[-1])
engineers_tasks = OrderedDict([tasks[:-1] for tasks in engineers_tasks])

test_sorted = {'Beta': engineers_tasks}
print json.dumps(test_sorted, indent=2)
```

Comment: @your solution is not working as OP asked , please try with some test cases, its not sorting by max no of elements.

Comment: `not sorting by max no of elements`? It produces the required result.

Answer (score -1):

This is not best solution but you can try.
For testing purpose i added one more item in the dict which have max elements called "SW Engineering33"

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test = {u'Beta': {
        u'SW Engineering': {
                u'Resolved': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 9, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 12, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 11, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 9, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 12, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 11, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 9, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 10, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 11, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 9},
                u'In Testing': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 7, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 7, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 7, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 7, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 7, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 7, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 7, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 7, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 7},
                u'Reopened': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 1, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 1, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 1, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 1, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
                u'Closed': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 17, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 18, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 18, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 17, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 18, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 18, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 17, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 18, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 18, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 17},
                u'Open': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 5, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 8, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 8, u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 5, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 8, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7, u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 5, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 8, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 8, u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 5}},

    u'SW Engineering33': {
        u'Resolved': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2,
                      u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3,
                      u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3,
                      u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},

        u'Resolved43': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 3, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 2,
                      u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 3, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 3,
                      u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 2, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 3,
                      u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
        u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 9, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 12, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 11,
                         u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 9, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 12, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 11,
                         u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 9, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 10, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 11,
                         u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 9},
        u'In Testing': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 7, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 7, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 7,
                        u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 7, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 7, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7,
                        u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 7, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 7, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 7,
                        u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 7},
        u'Reopened': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 1, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 1,
                      u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 1,
                      u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 1, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 1, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 1,
                      u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 1},
        u'Closed': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 17, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 18, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 18,
                    u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 17, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 18, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 18,
                    u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 17, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 18, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 18,
                    u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 17},
        u'Open': {u'2017-10-06 08:04:15': 5, u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 8, u'2017-10-11 00:19:29': 8,
                  u'2017-10-09 00:19:00': 5, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 8, u'2017-10-12 00:19:52': 7,
                  u'2017-10-08 00:18:58': 5, u'2017-10-10 00:19:31': 8, u'2017-10-13 00:19:28': 8,
                  u'2017-10-07 09:54:33': 5}},


        u'DSP Engineering': {
                u'In Progress': {u'2017-10-15 00:19:35': 1, u'2017-10-14 00:21:09': 1}}}}


capture_len={}

for key,value in test.items():
    for key1,value1 in value.items():
        for key3,value3 in value1.items():
            if key1 not in capture_len:
                capture_len[key1]=[value3]
            else:
                capture_len[key1].append(value3)

for_len={key:len(value) for key,value in capture_len.items()}




sorted_dict=sorted(for_len, key=for_len.get)


ordered_dict=OrderedDict()
for key,value in test.items():
    for k in sorted_dict:
        for key1,value1 in value.items():
            if k==key1:
                ordered_dict[k]=value1

final_dict={}
for key,value in ordered_dict.items():
    for key2,value2 in test.items():
        if key2 not in final_dict:
            final_dict[key2]=[(key,value)]
        else:
            final_dict[key2].append((key,value))

print  (final_dict)
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I am looking for, however, it mixes between objects in the key. Try with this list: https://pastebin.com/0nfjffcU